# Access framebuffer for arbitrary MacOS application

Tags: macos, graphics, macos-sierra, framebuffer

I am trying to capture the frame buffer for an arbitrary application on Mac and process the frame buffers, frame by frame. Is there a way to tap into an applications internal frame buffer? I also noticed there are some Graphics API functions like [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1455691-cgdisplaycreateimage) that can capture the entire screen, but I worry that

A) I'm going to need to figure out where my window is and crop it out of the entire screen image which may take a non-zero amount of time

B) Since it's capturing the entire screen instead of just one window, I imagine it'll take a longer amount of time.

I'm hoping to be able to capture and process 20 frames per second, so speed is pretty important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a couple of ideas...

Firstly, and most simply, you can start **Quicktime** (which is supplied with macOS) and go to `File`->`New screen recording` and record an arbitrary area of the screen and save it in a movie and analyse the frames later.

Secondly, you can use `screencapture` (`/usr/sbin/screencapture`) and either specify a rectangle to capture or a window id. The manual page is incorrect and rubbish, so use the following to see the actual options:

```
screencapture -h
```

**Output**

```
usage: screencapture [-icMPmwsWxSCUtoa] [files]
  -c         force screen capture to go to the clipboard
  -b         capture Touch Bar - non-interactive modes only
  -C         capture the cursor as well as the screen. only in non-interactive modes
  -d         display errors to the user graphically
  -i         capture screen interactively, by selection or window
               control key - causes screen shot to go to clipboard
               space key   - toggle between mouse selection and
                             window selection modes
               escape key  - cancels interactive screen shot
  -m         only capture the main monitor, undefined if -i is set
  -M         screen capture output will go to a new Mail message
  -o         in window capture mode, do not capture the shadow of the window
  -P         screen capture output will open in Preview
  -I         screen capture output will in a new Messages message
  -s         only allow mouse selection mode
  -S         in window capture mode, capture the screen not the window
  -t<format> image format to create, default is png (other options include pdf, jpg, tiff and other formats)
  -T<seconds> Take the picture after a delay of <seconds>, default is 5
  -w         only allow window selection mode
  -W         start interaction in window selection mode
  -x         do not play sounds
  -a         do not include windows attached to selected windows
  -r         do not add dpi meta data to image
  -l<windowid> capture this windowsid
  -R<x,y,w,h> capture screen rect
  -B<bundleid> screen capture output will open in app with bundleidBS
  files   where to save the screen capture, 1 file per screen
```

As you can see, the `-l`, `-R` options are very useful.

I wrote a little program to get a list of `windowids` [in another answer, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32842314/2836621).

The size of the window and the file format make a difference to the speed. I find `JPEG` is normally fastest, and `PNG` is normally slowest. I can get 20 frames a second with a reasonable size window using this:

```
time for i in {0..99}; do screencapture -l 56 -t jpg fred-$i.jpg; done
```

where I got the `56` from the `windowlist` program in my other, linked answer.

Comment: Quicktime won't be sufficient since I need to process in realtime, but screencapture looks perfect. I'll look into it, thank you so much!