# Obtain list of all window titles on macOS from a Python script

Tags: python, macos, pyobjc

I'd like to be able to obtain a list of strings of all the window titles on macOS from a Python script. On Windows, there's a win32 api (the enumWindows() function) that can do this; I'd like the macOS equivalent.

Is this possible? I assume I'll need to use pyobjc.

Comment: This might help a little https://stackoverflow.com/a/32842314/2836621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script is based on the comment by Mark Setchell and  prints application names and window names (using Python 3.7):

```
import Quartz

windows = Quartz.CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(Quartz.kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements|Quartz.kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly,Quartz.kCGNullWindowID);

for window in windows:
    print(f"{window[Quartz.kCGWindowOwnerName]}: {window.get(Quartz.kCGWindowName, '<no name>')}")
```

Note that windows may not have a name, hence the use of the "get" method to access the window name.