# is there any way to take a screenshot of specific window on Mac?

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, x11, xquartz

I wanted to capture only certain window using Imagemagick or Ffmpeg, but I heard that the x11 id needed for that is not supported on Mac.

The purpose is to capture the application window so that all areas are displayed even if some areas are out of the display and are not visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, applications on **macOS** use the native **Cocoa** framework to generate their GUI rather than X11. I'll write my answer to address each possibility in term, separating the two with a horizontal line.

---

#### With X11

You *can* install an X11 server called **XQuartz** on **macOS** using `homebrew` with:

```
brew cask install xquartz
```

However, only applications written to the X11 interface will create XQuartz windows and you can capture those windows in an X11 way, using `xwininfo` and passing the `id` to **ImageMagick**. However, relatively few apps use X11.

Let's just show that quickly with an example:

```
xeyes &                # start "xeyes" which is an X11 app and get our prompt back
xwininfo -name xeyes   # so we can get its id

...
...
xwininfo: Window id: 0xa0000a "xeyes"
...
...

# Tell ImageMagick to grab the "xeyes: window by its id and save as "xeyes.png"
magick import -window 0xa0000a xeyes.png
```

Another issue is that the **homebrew** version of **ImageMagick** doesn't support X11... so you'll have to either edit the **homebrew** formula, or run `./configure` yourself and include X11 support - which is non-trivial.

---

#### With native macOS Cocoa and 'screencapture'

If your app uses the native **Cocoa** interface, you can get its *"Cocoa id*" using a script I shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32842314/2836621). Slightly more simply, you can run some **AppleScript** to get the window id, e.g. to get the id of a window belonging to the **Terminal** app:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to id of window 1'
```

You can then use that id with the `screencapture` command supplied with **macOS** to hopefully do what you want with whatever application you are using. For example:

```
/usr/sbin/screencapture -l <WINDOWID> image.png
```

---

#### With 'ffmpeg'

On **macOS**, `ffmpeg` uses **AVFoundation** under the covers, so first you need to get the index that **AVFoundation** assigns to your screen, like this:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""

[AVFoundation indev @ 0x131e05df0] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x131e05df0] [0] FaceTime HD Camera
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x131e05df0] [1] Capture screen 0        <-- THIS LINE
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x131e05df0] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x131e05df0] [0] MacBook Pro Microphone
```

Look at the listing above and you can see that I must use device `[1]` if I want to record the screen. As I don't want sound recorded, I use `none` for the sound channel, so the basic `ffmpeg` command to record the screen on my Mac at 30fps will be:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -f avfoundation -i "1:none" ...
```

Now, you want to record a specific window, but `ffmpeg` doesn't know about windows, it only knows coordinates, so we need to find the coordinates of our window. Imagine I want to record **Safari** main window, first I get its location with:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to get the bounds of the front window'
87, 43, 1290, 538     # top-left x, top-left y, width, height
```

Now I tell `ffmpeg` to record that:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 30 -f avfoundation -i "1:none" -vf "crop=1290:538:87:43" screen.mp4
```

and it appears to work, but doesn't! Apparently there's no atom and `ffplay` can't play stuff without atoms. It transpires that atoms get written at the end of the video - unless you Control-C out of them. So, you can now make sure you don't need to Control-C by adding a duration of 5 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 30 -f avfoundation -i "1:none" -t 5 -vf "crop=1290:538:87:43" screen.mp4
```

That also appears to work, but doesn't actually work either. You can play it with `ffplay` but not Apple's **QuickTime** which only likes `yuv420p` format, so you can actually do what you want with:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 30 -f avfoundation -i "1:none" -t 5 -vf "crop=1290:538:87:43,format=yuv420p" screen.mp4
```

Comment: Impressive knowledge!

Comment: I appreciate your excellent answer. It's been a huge help.

Comment: My pleasure - good luck with your project!