# cv2.VideoCapture(0) read frame from a different camera for each run

Tags: python, macos, opencv, computer-vision

I ran into a very strange problem that appeared out of nowhere, the same code did not cause this problem before.

The following code, the first time I ran it, it read the frame from my connected external camera; the second time I ran it, it read the frame from my MacBook's built-in camera; the third time it read the frame from the external camera.

It just keeps switching and I don't know how to fix it, I want `cameraCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` to always get the frame from the external camera.

```py
import cv2

cameraCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

# read
success, frame = cameraCapture.read()
while success and cv2.waitKey(1) == -1:
    img = frame

    cv2.imshow("Mine", img)
    success, frame = cameraCapture.read()
```

Is there any way I can get the data of a certain numbered camera, such as name, resolution, etc.?

Comment: IIUC, OpenCV uses `ffmpeg` under the covers to record video. Have a look at the `ffmpeg` part of my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74325989/2836621 You may find the `AVFoundation` command allows you to predict the parameter for `cv2.VideoCapture()` or that you can use `ffmpeg` directly to read and pipe frames into your OpenCV code instead of that if it isn't working for you.

Comment: no, for video devices it **does not** use ffmpeg. it uses native apis (or gstreamer).

Comment: yes, this is a problem with OpenCV. the mapping from devices to plain dumb indices may not be deterministic. just file a bug about this, and please state that you're using MacOS (i.e. API is probably AVFoundation). eventually they'll have to improve OpenCV's API such that one can actually pass a device identifier (also enumerate devices). this indices stuff is just useless and prevents OpenCV from being used for serious applications (with multiple cameras).

Answer (score -2):

You can use `cameraCapture.get(<property id>)` to get different properties of the capture device. There's a full list of them [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d), but the ones you're looking for are:

- `cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` for the width
- `cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT` for the height.

Comment: that will always be initialized to the default of 640x480 by OpenCV, so it can't be used to identify a camera.